# How to turn off "Tap to Unmute" on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist, mute, youtube-watch-later

How do you turn off the "Tap to Unmute" feature on YouTube playlists?

I created a long playlist of videos to 'watch later' for the purpose of streaming them to my TV in sequence automatically (streaming from my iPad via Apple TV). It is extremely annoying to have to get up to unmute every video EVERY TIME a new video starts.

I cannot find a way to turn the feature off or disable it.

[image]
<sup><sup>*Photo courtesy [PikiTheYandere](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/167038/pikutheyandere)*</sup></sup>

Comment: I have the same problem, spent at least one hour with a second level technician from Apple and the only thing he found in his research was your post.

Answer (score 1):

Original poster is using a YouTube playlist not playing from Facebook thumbnails. Plus I'm encountering this issue, playing from YouTube website in Chrome for mobile.

I've seen multiple answers on multiple sites, all different. Try [this from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/31ev23/every_youtube_video_starts_muted_anyone_who_knows/):

Apparently YouTube tries to smart remember what it thinks your preferred volume is. To clear that setting, clear your browser cache. Or...

If you slide the volume slider down, it saves your settings. If you click it down it will not. To unmute it on start, slide the slider up instead of clicking it on.

Answer (score 0):

To disable tap to unmute on YouTube site accessed via browser, download YouTube app from App Store. Restart Safari, launch video on browser and play a few videos. Tap to unmute should be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The “Tap To unmute“ shows on YouTube videos when clicking on the thumbnail from the Facebook app, from my experience and it shows only if you play a YouTube video from Facebook and nowhere else. If you play the video from Safari or YouTube directly there is no problem.